# change startAdress after reading finished on Nmodbus c#

Tags: c#

i have a method that reads holding registers from energy meter with Nmodbus.
my problem is that some of the registers are on 400139 and above, the limit for numOFPoint is 125.
i cant find a way to change the startAdress to 139 and continue to read from there.
please your help.

```
private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1WasClicked = true;
            try
            {
                byte slaveAddress = byte.Parse(ConnectionSetUp.SetValueForAdress);
                ushort startAddress = 0;
                ushort numOfPoints = 24;
                IModbusMaster masterRTU = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(serialPort);
                ushort[] result = masterRTU.ReadHoldingRegisters  (slaveAddress, startAddress,
                numOfPoints);

                //display result.
                VoltR.Text = string.Empty;
                
                VoltR.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[0]);
                VoltS.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[1]);
                VoltT.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[2]);
                CurrentR.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[3]);
                CurrentS.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[5]);
                CurrentT.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[7]);
                Kw_R.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[19]);
                Kw_S.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[21]);
                Kw_T.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[23]);
                

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read only exact registers by creating enum with specific addresses.
For example:

```
private enum enRegistersAddr
{
    Volt = 0,
    Current = 20,
    Kw = 140
}


private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1WasClicked = true;
        try
        {
            byte slaveAddress = byte.Parse(ConnectionSetUp.SetValueForAdress);
            
            IModbusMaster masterRTU = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(serialPort);
            
            ushort numOfPoints = 3;

            ushort[] result = masterRTU.ReadHoldingRegisters  (slaveAddress, 
                  (ushort)enRegistersAddr.Volt, numOfPoints);

            //display result.
            VoltR.Text = string.Empty;

            VoltR.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[0]);
            VoltS.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[1]);
            VoltT.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[2]);

            result = masterRTU.ReadHoldingRegisters  (slaveAddress, 
               (ushort)enRegistersAddr.Current, numOfPoints);

            CurrentR.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[0]);
            CurrentS.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[1]);
            CurrentT.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[2]);

            result = masterRTU.ReadHoldingRegisters  (slaveAddress, 
               (ushort)enRegistersAddr.Kw, numOfPoints);

            Kw_R.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[0]);
            Kw_S.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[1]);
            Kw_T.Text = string.Format("{0}", result[2]);

            
            

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
               MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for kind support

Comment: sorry but i have a new problem, if i choose a wrong slave ID, instead of getting an exception from Nmodbus after no respond from slave, my form hangs. can you please help again?

Comment: Try to set Read timeout to transport. `masterRTU.Transport.ReadTimeout = 1000;`